# Git push to Heroku under Cygwin fails

Tags: git, heroku, cygwin, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to deploy my first rails app to Heroku using Cygwin but have run into a problem.

MSysGit is installed and is being used by Cygwin. I can see this by running `git --version` under Cygwin and get `git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0`

I set the HOME variable to `%USERPATH%` and Cygwin starts from there. There was a .ssh directory there so I cd'ed into it and used ssh-keygen to create the keys.

I am able to setup Heroku and upload the keys correctly. All steps work correctly till I try to **push** the files. I am able to use TortoiseGit (I like using MSysGit with a visual GUI) and am able to **push** to the server but when the rails bit comes around, the push fails. By fails, I mean there is no output. So I ran a trace on it and got this:

```
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@heroku.com' 'git-receive-pack '\''nameXXXX.git'\'''
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be missing?

Thanks!

*edited to add more information*

Answer (score 0):

For an SSH URL, it is possible the private SSH key that Tortoise can access is not in `%HOME%`.
Especially if `HOME` is set to `%USERPATH%` ([which does not exist by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43934167/6309))

Set `HOME` instead to `%USERPROFILE%,` and make sure there is a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa(.pub)` in it.