# How to get only the user path variable?

Tags: batch-file

`Echo %PATH%` returns **system** PATH variable + **user** PATH variable.

How to get only the **user** PATH variable?

Answer (score 14):

The **system** `PATH` variable is stored in Windows registry with value `Path` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` containing references to environment variables like `%SystemRoot%` or if not correct modified by an application of type `REG_SZ` without environment variable references under the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

The **user** `PATH` variable does not exist by default in Windows registry. It is stored in Windows registry with value `Path` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` or `REG_SZ` once created by an application or manually by the user under the registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

The external command **REG** with command `QUERY` can be used to **read** the value of the **system** or the **user** `PATH` variable directly from Windows registry with standard user permissions.

It is possible to read the **user** `PATH` variable from Windows registry and assign its value to an environment variable `UserPath` with additionally expanding all environment variables in directory paths list.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "UserPath="
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKCU\Environment" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do if /I "%%G" == "Path" (
    if /I "%%H" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" (call set "UserPath=%%I") else if /I "%%H" == "REG_SZ" set "UserPath=%%I"
    if defined UserPath goto UserPathRead
)
echo User PATH is not defined or has no string value.
goto EndBatch

:UserPathRead
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo The user PATH is: !UserPath!
endlocal

:EndBatch
echo/
pause
endlocal
```

The output format of `reg query` depends on version of Windows which makes the additional case-insensitive **IF** condition necessary. For details on `reg query` output format see for example [Reading NT's Registry with REG Query](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntregquery.php) written by Rob van der Woude.

Example output of `reg query HKCU\Environment /v Path` **on Windows XP**:

```
! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    Path        REG_SZ  C:\BatUtils
```

There is an empty line at beginning and one more at end of the output as well as a header line and one more empty line above the line with the registry key.

The line with the data of interest starts with four space characters and has next the case-insensitive name of the registry value `Path`. Then a *single horizontal tab* character is output left to the registry value type `REG_SZ`. Last there is one more *horizontal tab* character before the string value of `Path` is output which could contain also one or more space characters.

Example output of `reg query HKCU\Environment /v Path` **on Windows Vista** or newer Windows versions:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    Path    REG_SZ    C:\BatUtils
```

There is also an empty line at beginning and one more at end of the output. But there is no header. The second line contains already the registry key.

The line with the data of interest starts with four space characters and has next the case-insensitive name of the registry value `Path`. Then *four spaces* instead of a tab are output left to the registry value type `REG_SZ`. Last there are again *four spaces* instead of a tab before the string value of `Path` is output which could contain also one or more space characters.

The command **REG** is executed in a separate command process in background by **FOR**. The error message output by **REG** to handle **STDERR** in case of registry key `HKCU\Environment` or value `Path` do not exist is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL** with `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal character on parsing **FOR** command line by Windows command interpreter, but as redirection operator on later execution of **REG** command line in separate background command process.

The **FOR** options defined with `"skip=2 tokens=1,2*"` result in skipping the first two lines of **REG** output and splitting the other lines up into three substrings (tokens) using the default delimiters space and tab.

The first space/tab delimited string is assigned to first loop variable `G` which is the name of the variable on reaching the line with the data of interest.

The second substring being the registry value type is assigned to loop variable `H` being the next character in [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/). This behavior is the reason why **FOR** loop variables are case-sensitive.

Everything after spaces/tabs after second substring is assigned to loop variable `I` without splitting up the rest of the line because of `*` in options string after `tokens=1,2`.

So on Windows Vista and later Windows versions the command **FOR** processes as first line from output of **REG** the line with `Path` while on Windows XP the first line processed is the line with the registry key which is the reason why the first **IF** condition is necessary.

The second **IF** condition makes a case-insensitive string comparison to find out the type of the registry value with name `Path`. The string assigned to `Path` contains on type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` one or more environment variable references. For that reason the command `call` is used which results in parsing the string value read from the registry and assigned to the loop variable `I` by the Windows command processor to expand all environment variable references before command **SET** is executed to assign the expanded string value to environment variable `UserPath`.

**Note:** `cmd.exe` searches for an executable or script with name `set` using the local environment variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH` because of the usage of command **CALL**. The command **CALL** is designed for calling a batch file from within a batch file and not to force the Windows command processor to parse a command line a second time.

The third **IF** condition is executed only if the registry value `Path` is not of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. It compares case-insensitive the registry value type against the string `REG_SZ` in which case the string value of `Path` can be assigned directly to the environment variable `UserPath`.

The environment variable `UserPath` is explicitly undefined above the **FOR** loop. So if the current line has as first string `Path` in any case and the registry value type is `REG_EXPAND_SZ` or `REG_SZ`, there should be now defined the environment variable `UserPath` as otherwise there is either a registry value `Path` with wrong type or with an empty string. It is possible to have `Path` stored in Windows registry with an empty string, but it is not possible to define the environment variable `UserPath` with an empty string.

The fourth **IF** condition verifies that the environment variable `UserPath` is really defined with a non-empty string. In this case the command **GOTO** is used to exit the **FOR** loop on having successfully read the **user** `PATH` variable from Windows registry by jumping to the command block for further processing the environment variable `UserPath`.

The command block below the **FOR** loop is reached if the **user** `PATH` variable does not exist at all in Windows registry, or is of wrong type, or exists with an empty string.

For completeness a batch code to

- read **system** AND **user** `PATH` from Windows registry without expansion,
- concatenate both `PATH` variables to `PATH` with overwriting **local** `PATH` in current command process in current environment,
- expand all environment variable references now if necessary at all.
- replace all `;;` by `;` in `PATH` value and
- remove `;` from end of `PATH` value if there is one.

This batch code does not check if **user** `PATH` contains one or more directory paths being already present in **system** `PATH` before concatenating them. So it is possible that a directory path is in **local** `PATH` finally present more than once.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Get directly from Windows registry the system PATH variable value.
set "PathExpand="
set "PathSystem="
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do if /I "%%G" == "Path" (
    if /I "%%H" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" (set "PathExpand=1" & set "PathSystem=%%I") else if /I "%%H" == "REG_SZ" set "PathSystem=%%I"
    if defined PathSystem goto GetUserPath
)

rem Get directly from Windows registry the user PATH variable value.
:GetUserPath
set "PathUser="
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKCU\Environment" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do if /I "%%G" == "Path" (
    if /I "%%H" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" (set "PathExpand=1" & set "PathUser=%%I") else if /I "%%H" == "REG_SZ" set "PathUser=%%I"
    if defined PathUser goto SetPath
)

rem Concatenate the two PATH values to a single value.
rem Expand the environment variable references if that is necessary at all.
rem Next replace all two consecutive semicolons by a single semicolon.
rem Last remove semicolon from end of the directories list if there is one.

:SetPath
set "PATH=%PathSystem%;%PathUser%"
if defined PathExpand call set "PATH=%PATH%"
set "PATH=%PATH:;;=;%"
if "%PATH:~-1%" == ";" set "PATH=%PATH:~0,-1%"

rem Output the environment variables PATH and PATHEXT and all other
rem environment variables starting case-insensitive with the string
rem Path as used in this batch file code to see what happened here.
set PATH
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` and the answer on Stack Overflow topic [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for meaning of operator `&` on a command line.

Answer (score -5):

`echo %USERPROFILE%`

...might be what op was looking for